# The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $[0].Price | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 16

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Products",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18,2)",nullable: false),
                PictureUrl = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                ProductTypeId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                ProductBrandId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Description = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 180, nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 100, nullable: false)
            },
```

this is the snippet for creating the table

```
 public static async Task SeedAsync(StoreContext context, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        try 
        {
            if (!context.ProductsBrands.Any())
            {
                var brandsData = File.ReadAllText("../Infrastructure/Data/SeedData/brands.json");

                var brands = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ProductBrand>>(brandsData);
                

                foreach (var item in brands) 
                {
                    context.ProductsBrands.Add(item);
                }

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

in this part i tried to seed the data into the table from my json file but i am unable to do so and i am not getting any changes in my table.

pls help.

Comment: Please add code for `ProductBrand` and your json.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, in your JSON file you use double-quotes in the Price element.
Like: { Price: "0000000.00"},
Try it without the quotes.
If it not works, then maybe your JSON is broken.